# Plot random times on consistent time axis in excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2016

I have data like this:
[image: raw data]

I would like it plotted on a chart in Excel, with the X axis having times like this:
7:00 AM
7:30 AM
8:00 AM
etc.

And have the point intersections relative to the appropriate time. So, the 7:10 entry would appear a little after 7:00 on the chart. 7:51 would be between 7:30 and 8:00, and so forth.

Not sure how to better define this, or how to get this in Excel.

Update, here's my X axis properties:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Major unit of your graph to 0.04167 (the minor should automatically adjust to 0.008334):

[image]

I also recommend to adjust the time type (Number -> Category: Time -> Type: (no seconds)
and it should look quite decent. (I don't have US settings, therefore my AM/PM is not shown automatically)

---

You can always force time format if doesn't show up (ignore my type is my regional settings):

[image]

---

EDIT, for half hour set Major to: 0.020835.

One can also adjust the start range by multiplying 0.4167 with the hours you want to start. In our case 7:00 AM, so 0.04167 * 7 = 0.29169.

[image]

Comment: Okay, so I misspoke. I wanted my times on my X axis. I do not see Bounds unless I change the Axis type to Date. But I can't change to the values you have.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. Needed a scatter chart. Not sure why tho, but I guess it's more flexible.

Comment: No problem, I also noticed if you set the minimum value to 0.29169, your chart starts at 7:00 AM :)